# Mapquest window not displaying when using percentages to size div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mapquest

Trying to display a map on a page at width:100%. When I specify a size in the html

```
<div id="mapquest" style="width:400px; height:400px">
</div>
```

The div is all full of sweet map, without any problems. However when I attempt to specify it with a percentage:

```
<div id="mapquest" style="width:100%; height:auto"> <!--or height:100%, or even height:400px>-->
</div>
```

The console logs the width of my div in this case as the width of the parent container, but the height is 0.

This also happens when I try to assign the same element style properties in the external CSS stylesheet. Before I drop another hour on troubleshooting, I was wondering if there might be a known reason this doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the object returned by Mapquest in this case,

```
(function(){

MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function() {

    /*Create an object for options*/
    var mqopts={
      elt:document.getElementById('mapquest'),  /*ID of element on the page where you want the map added*/
      zoom:20,                                  /*initial zoom level of the map*/
      latLng:{lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089},  /*center of map in latitude/longitude */
      mtype:'map',                              /*map type (map)*/
      bestFitMargin:0,                          /*margin offset from the map viewport when applying a bestfit on shapes*/
      zoomOnDoubleClick:true                    /*zoom in when double-clicking on map*/
    };

    /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/
    window.mapquest = new MQA.TileMap(mqopts);
    });
})();
```

changes the position of the div to relative, and requires a size argument in px, it's default being 0. My understanding is that since it is the last style argument passed to the element on load, it overrides any preceding styles. Now a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline style, use external css file to speed up the load time.

Now you answer: Add the height width property to that ID.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="mapquest"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mapquest{
    width:400px;/* pixel or percentage */
    height:400px;/* pixel or percentage */
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the object that the mapquest API returns overrides my external styles.

Comment: Please do it and see what it shows. If wrong will show, comment with that link, so that I can solve it easily. you can use google map api instead of mapquest api.

Comment: The styles in the project, **are** in an external stylesheet. And for my project, I don't want just google maps, I want **all of the maps**.

Comment: If I will see the link where your map appears, I definitely solve the issue.

Comment: Dude, there's no link, it isn't deployed.

Comment: Okay then use !Important tag to override the external styles.

width:400px !important;
height:400px !important;

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the MapQuest JavaScript API are you using?  Version 7.1 (the latest - released a few weeks ago) had some tweaks related to CSS styles overriding other popular libraries like Twitter bootstrap, so please check it out to see if it solves the problem at hand: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.1

Disclaimer: I work for MapQuest.  While we don't explicitly support third-party libraries, I know that 7.1 had some CSS-related changes so maybe this one will help you?